# Assuming $z$ as a complex number,find all solutions to the equation $|i^z|=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Assuming $z$ as a complex number,find all solutions to the equation $|i^z|=1$.

My try: here i am confused because for any integer value of z ,it satisfies the equation.

Comment: Write $i$ in polar form,  write $z=a+bi$ and then figure out what $a$ and $b$ can possibly be if $|i^z|=1$.

Comment: How do you define $$i^z$$ when $z$ is a complex number and not a natural integer?

Comment: Is $i^z$ the principal branch or set-valued?

Comment: Why does this have two votes to close as unclear what's being asked?  How can this be made more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$i^z = i^{x+iy} = i^x i^{iy} = i^x \cdot (i^i)^y$$

What's $i^i$?  It's

$$i^i = e^{\operatorname{Log}(i^i)} = e^{i\operatorname{Log}i} = e^{i(\ln|i| + i\pi/2)} = e^{i^2\pi/2} = e^{-\pi/2}$$

So then $$|i^z| = |i^x \cdot (i^i)^y| = |i^x \cdot (e^{-\pi/2})^y| = |i^x \cdot e^{-\pi y/2}| = |i^x| \cdot |e^{-\pi y/2}| = 1 \cdot |e^{-\pi y/2}|$$

At this point, we want all values of $y$ such that $|e^{-\pi y/2}| = 1$.  In other words, we want all $y$ such that $e^{-\pi y/2} = \pm 1$.  Well, since $y$ is real, then $e^{-\pi y/2} \ne -1$, and the only time we have $e^{-\pi y/2} = 1$ is when $y=0$.

Thus $x$ can be any real number and $y$ must be zero, which means the solution to $|i^z| = 1$ is $z \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use exponential form: $\;i=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2}$, hence
$$i^z=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{z\,i\,\pi}2}$$
If $z=a+ib$, there results
$$\bigl\lvert i^z\bigr\rvert=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{b\pi}2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ and $z=a+bi$, so you get

$$ |i^z| =| e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}(a+bi) } |= |e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2} }e^{\frac{-b\pi}{2}}| = |e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2} }| |e^{\frac{-b\pi}{2}}| = |e^{\frac{-b\pi}{2}}| = e^{\frac{-b\pi}{2}} =1=e^0 \to  b = 0$$

so the solution is every real number $a$.